# MSVC fails to compile SFINAE checks

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

Is there some compiler flag I should be aware of? The following code works just fine and as intended according to GCC and Clang but not MSVC. What makes `std::allocator`'s allocate so different here?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
constexpr bool declares_allocate = false;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool declares_allocate<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::allocate)>> = true;

struct normal_struct {

    auto allocate() -> void {}

};

template <typename T>
struct struct_template {

    auto allocate() -> void {}

};

template <typename T>
class class_template_public {

    public:
        auto allocate() -> void {}

};

template <typename T>
class class_template_private {

    private:
        auto allocate() -> void {}

};


auto main() -> int {

    auto allocator = std::allocator<float>();
    auto memory = allocator.allocate(1024);

    static_assert(declares_allocate<normal_struct>);                    // pass
    static_assert(declares_allocate<struct_template<float>>);           // pass
    static_assert(declares_allocate<class_template_public<float>>);     // pass
//  static_assert(declares_allocate<class_template_private<float>>);    // fails
    static_assert(declares_allocate<std::allocator<float>>);            // fails when compiled by MSVC but not Clang or GCC

    allocator.deallocate(memory, 1024);

    return 0;

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GVyNQZ

Comment: I'm not sure how well-specified variable template partial specializations are, if at all. Does the problem persist if you use a class template and partial specialization to define a static variable instead?

Comment: I think `std::allocator<T>::allocate` is overloaded between C++17 and C++20.

Comment: Yes, it works if you use `decltype(static_cast<float*(T::*)(std::size_t)>(&T::allocate))` or `decltype(static_cast<float*(T::*)(std::size_t, const void*)>(&T::allocate))`

Comment: Looks like MSVC declares some non-standard overload of `allocate()`, that's not specified in the C++ standard. So, what else is new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the C++ standard implementation, `std::allocator<T>::allocate` can be defined as:

---

```
T* allocate(size_t n, const void* hint = 0);
```

---

```
T* allocate(size_t n);
T* allocate(size_t n, const void* hint); // deprecating usage of hint
```

---

```
T* allocate(size_t n);
```

---

That is, the second implementation turns `allocate` into an overloaded member function. And that one is currently used in [MSVC's standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/xmemory#L803):

```
_NODISCARD __declspec(allocator) _Ty* allocate(_CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW const size_t _Count) {
    return static_cast<_Ty*>(_Allocate<_New_alignof<_Ty>>(_Get_size_of_n<sizeof(_Ty)>(_Count)));
}

_CXX17_DEPRECATE_OLD_ALLOCATOR_MEMBERS _NODISCARD __declspec(allocator) _Ty* allocate(
    _CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW const size_t _Count, const void*) {
    return allocate(_Count);
}
```

Such implementation makes `&T::allocate` ambiguous, and thus rejected during substitution.